# Please help me understand how $\overline{\bigcup A_\alpha}\subset \bigcup \overline{A_\alpha}$ does not hold in general.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

From Munkres Topology section $17$ on Closed Sets and Limit Points.

[image]

I have seen answers that say if we pick some neighborhood of $x$ it may intersect some $A_\alpha$, but another neighborhood of $x$ may not intersect this same $A_\alpha$.

However, why do we care if two different neighborhoods do not intersect the same $A_\alpha$ as long as it intersects some $A_\alpha$? After all, we are trying to show that $x$ is in the union of the closures.

Comment: Because $x$ isn’t in $\operatorname{cl}A_\alpha$ unless ***every*** nbhd of $x$ intersects $A_\alpha$.

Comment: Note $x$ isn't in $A_a$.  just *a* neighborhood of $x$ has a point *not equal to x* in it.  For $x$ to be in $\overline{A_a}$ if $x$ is not, we need *every* neighborhood to have a point in $A_a$ and we have no reason for that to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects the union; therefore intersects some $A_\alpha$. But a smaller open neighborhood may intersect $A_\beta$ and a smaller one than that may intersect $A_\gamma$, etc. and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\ldots$ can be distinct.  Thus you haven't shown that there's just *one* $A_\alpha$ that will continue to be intersected by every open neighborhood of $x$ no matter how small the neighborhood gets.  In other words, you haven't shown that there is some $\alpha$ for which $x$ is in the closure of $A_\alpha$.

Identifying this flaw in the proof doesn't mean the proposition is false; it only means you haven't proved it's true.  To show it's false you'd use a counterexample.  Here is a counterexample:
$$
A_n = \left( \frac 1 n, \frac 1 n + \frac 1 {n^2} \right).
$$
Then $\displaystyle 0 \in \overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}$ but $\displaystyle 0 \notin \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{A_n}.$

The counterexample may shed some light on the fallacy of the argument.  For every $\varepsilon>0$, you have some $n$ so large that the neighborhood $(-\varepsilon,+\varepsilon)$ of $0$ intersects the union.  But there is no $A_n$ that intersects the neighborhood $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) = \left( -\frac 1{2n}, +\frac 1 {2n} \right).$  That neighborhood separates $0$ from $A_n$, so that $0$ is not in the closure of $A_n$.

Comment: Your second paragraph has a (true) converse: finding a counterexample is not the same as finding a flaw in a proof, but merely showing that a flaw exists. On the other hand, a concrete counterexample (such as the one you've given) makes it much easier to find (and *understand*) a flaw by simply trying to apply the proof to the particular example.

Answer (score 1):

As let be $x$  a limit point of $\bigcup A_a$ with $x$ not necessarily in any $A_a$. The neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point $y \ne x$ in $\bigcup A_a$.  But that is only *one* neighbor hood.  To be a limit point for that one particular $A_a$ *every* neighborhood of $x$ must intersect *that* $A_a$.  But you only know that every neighborhood intersects *some*, maybe different $A_a$.  If each neighborhood intersect *different* $A_a$ then $x$ is not necessarily a limit point to any.

Consider for example $A_i = \{i/z\mid z \in \mathbb Z-\setminus\{0\}\}$.  Then $\overline{A_i} = A_i$.  And $\bigcup A_i = \mathbb Q$ and $\overline {\bigcup A_i} = \mathbb R \not \subset \bigcup {\overline A_i} = \mathbb Q$.

Consider the "proof" for $x$, $x$ irrational, then every neighborhood $U$ intersects some $A_i$.  Say $x = \pi$ and $3.2 \in N(1/10,\pi)=U$. So $U$ intersects $A_{32}$ as $3.2 = 32/10$ (and $|\pi - 3.2| < 1/10$).  But $N(1/20,\pi)$ need not intersect $A_{32}$.  Indeed  $32/10 - \pi= 3.2 - \pi > .05$ and $\pi - 32/9 = \pi = 2.909090\ldots > .05$.  So $\pi \not \in \overline {A_{32}}$. (But $N(1/20,\pi)$ intersects $A_{31}$... but $N(1/100, \pi)$ doesn't... and so on...)

Indeed every neighborhood *does* intersect *an* $A_i$ but there is *no* $A_i$ that is intersected by *all* neighborhoods and $\pi$ is not in *any* $\overline{A_i}$.

Comment: The notation $\cup$ is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, and $\bigcup$ is used in things like $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n\in\mathcal N} A_n.$  I edited accordingly.  (Also, not the use of \mid.) $\qquad$

Comment: Typo: "Also, note the use of \mid." $\qquad$